# How do I check if the document formatting is right?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

I have to submit a paper to a competition. They have strict rules on the formatting that is to be used. For example,  the size of the font, the margin, the space between the paragraph and so on.

I have tried my best, from the onset, to stick to the formatting guidelines. However, I am wondering **how to check these rules in an automated way**, simply to find any errors that may be missed by the human eye.

I have both OpenOffice and Microsoft Office 2007.

Comment: Yup, it's called LaTeX ;)

Comment: @terdon Temme how I can use it to verify if I have formatted my document right xD

Comment: You can't, that was just a tongue-in-cheek joke (that's why I did  not post an answer). LaTeX is an extremely powerful, full-fledged typesetting system. If you had written your paper using it, it would have dealt with all formatting issues but it won't help you if you have written using something else unless you convert your document to LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of an automated tool, but you may try one of these hints:

1. If you used a "living template", i.e., a document provided from the competition to fill your text in, then use its styles and

   - paste all text as plain text (no rich-text, no html, no whatever-else)
   - never change formatting manually like bold, margin, etc. always apply the styles from the template.
2. If there is a low number of predefined styles to use, then check every style and show where it is applied.
3. You may want to write a macro that runs through your document. However, I am not aware of any macros for "style checking".
4. Print it. It may not seem obvious, but the human eye detects formatting errors a lot better on paper than on screen.

The last hint - and probably the best one - is to follow the guide from the competition. If they care much about formatting, then they provide a good documentation to follow.